# create a dynamic image slideshow with python

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, python-imaging-library

I need to dynamically add images to a video template with place holders for photos in order to generate a slide-show.
I need something of 
[this format](http://videohive.net/item/watercolor-frames/15594607?s_rank=1). Basically I will have a video template and images as my input. And the output has to be in **mp4**  format.
Any suggestions on which python libraries to use and how I can go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Verify is [moviepy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/moviepy) can help you.

Maybe you can use ffmeg to encode based on some input generated by python.